# Spacing/width issue with my CSS3

Tags: html, css

I am not sure why there is a spacing (margin/padding) to the left in the second and third tabs.  The test site location is: http://new.vonsazkin.com/index.aspx

Click on **Residents** in top menu and then click on the **Events** tab or the Records tab.  You'll notice that the grid is pushed down. If I set the width of the grid to auto, then it moves up where I want it, but it shrinks.  The max width I can set is 66.67% but it is shifted to the right.  I want the grid to be 100% width and not have the spacing on top.  You can right click in the browser and click the Inspect Element option to view the page code and CSS for the site.

Any clue?

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is absolute position the table when its parent is relatively positioned.

```
.resident_workspace_form .table-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.resident_workspace_form table.alt {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: This works, but this is just hacking the real problem (which could break your UI). Real problems lies in your css: .residents_block .tab-pane { display: block; } Believe me :)

Comment: @user1100221 Removing `.resident_workspace_form .table-wrapper { display:block; }` will solve the button alignment as Kantoci suggested.

Comment: @Sen Jacob That is a much better suggestion.  It is working in my local machine now.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Interesting :) I found where the problem is: `style.css`

```
.residents_block .tab-pane {
    display: block;
    ...
```

This `display: block` is messing with showing/hiding tabs. With this CSS other tabs are there but have `opacity: 0`. I believe this is some custom css (which breaks bootstrap functionality) and you should remove it...

Comment: @user1100221 This should be the answer

Answer (score 1):

[The padding between tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgqjB.png)

I didn't really understand what's your problem, but if you have in mind the space between the tabs - you have padding. Also tabs have height at media (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 992px) [The height of tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKw7R.png).

Comment: I have added screenshots to explain the issue.  With the table/grid width at 100%, it gets pushed down.  If I reduce the width to 66%, it moves up and to the right.  Anything more than 66%, it moves down.  Thanks.